# Hello World App Engine .NET app has latency of ~500ms

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I followed the tutorial in the Google Cloud Platform console for creating a new App Engine with .NET as the "language", and by the last steps published the Hello World program at the public endpoint at
https://myproject.appspot.com

However when testing this in my browser, I consistently get response times of upwards of 400 ms.
Testing a simple .NET app on a Linode yields about 100 ms latency.

Do I need to manually configure the app to be able to have a more normal response time? It doesn't seem to be the highly performant, scalable solution it says it is, if just a simple Hello World has about 0,5 seconds of latency...

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you and your GAE app are in different [locations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations). There is a 600ms difference between two requests to my app: one from San Francisco, the other from Amsterdam.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. You are right that we're in different locations - since Firebase restricts the GAE instances of the project to be in the US Central location. However, accessing simple Hello World apps should still not take this long. I can access a Linode or Azure app in the same US location with about 40-50 ms latency from Europe. I managed to implement what I needed using Azure Functions instead (also located in the US), with performance an order of magnitude faster than the GAE. It's weird to me that Google would be so location sensitive yet not support different locations

Comment: @Christian Can you have a look at [this article](https://cloudplatform.googleblog.com/2015/08/How-to-Troubleshoot-Latency-in-Your-App-Engine-Application.html) and provide the output of the curl command in the question description so that we could analyze with more information?